# Usage of the word "Replenish" in Genesis 1:28

Tags: genesis

Why in the Genesis narrative does God use the word REPLENISH when he tasks Adam with the responsibility of earth? There was no lifeform before creation of Adam , Eve and other lifeforms. So why did Adam have to REPLENISH?

Replenish by definition: 
1.1Restore (a stock or supply) to a former level or condition:

Comment: Please [edit] this to quote from your preferred translation which uses the word replenish.

Comment: -1. We discuss about Bible text hermeneutics, only in second instance we may (if it is the case) discuss about some ways to translate a particular - and yet examined -  Bible passage.

Answer (score 4):

The KJV is alone in translating that as "replenish" and this is simply because in 1611 the word meant "to supply fully":

http://biblehub.com/genesis/1-28.htm

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/replenish

Comment: On the other hand,  [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=replenish#:~:text=Specifically,replenishment)says "*Specifically as "to fill up again, restore to a former amount or condition" by 1610s.*".

Answer (score 2):

The word **וּמִלְא֥וּ**(ū·mil·’ū) is translated in the [Brown-Driver-Briggs](https://archive.org/stream/hebrewenglishlex00browuoft#page/569/mode/1up) as:

> *verb be full, fill (Late Hebrew id. (Piʿel transitive); Zinjirli מלא
>   (Piʿel transitive) DHMSendsch. 60; Assyrian malû (transitive and
>   intransitive) DlHWB 409; Arabic  (transitive) ,  (intransitive);
>   Ethiopic  (transitive and intransitive); Aramaic  (transitive), מְלָא
>   (intransitive and transitive), Palmyrene proper name מלא = plenitude,
>   VogPalm 7, 2 and others; Sabean מלא Os14 Levy-OsZMG xix.1863, 211 f.
>   DHMZMG xxix.1875, 595); —*

Interestingly, the root word "**מִלְא֤**"(male or mala) means " be full, *usually with accusative material"*. The general sense is that man was given "dominion" (*וּרְד֞וּ*-ū·rə·ḏū) to "bring order" to the earth God had created which was "full" and needs harvesting. Apart from man's dominion, the earth would 'over-run' and cease from being productive. It 'replenishes' itself because of man's exercising dominion over it.

Comment: Just a note on BDB: "Qal 2" actually lists this usage (which is not piel and not with an accusative [of] material). FWIW, I would have read this verb as having more to do with what precedes ("be fruitful and multiply...") than what follows ("subdue...and have dominion") (cf. 1:22), but that's just me.

Comment: @Susan I looked at that as well; but the "Subdue and Have Dominion" are part of the same passage. Creation was untainted by sin at this point, yet required 'dominion'. The 'replenish' aspect would make no sense if there were no need to replenish 'from'. I will stand corrected if it is not accusative, but I believe it is the best way to explain why the KJV chose 'replenish', rather than full, or fullness, which doesn't make contextual sense(IMO).

Comment: It has an accusative (*hāʾāreṣ* = the earth), but it's not "of material". The verb is unusual in that within the *qal* stem it can mean *either* "to be full of" -- which takes an accusative describing the composition ("material") of the fullness, e.g. "the earth is full of **his steadfast love**" (Ps 119, etc.), and indeed "the earth is full of **his creatures**" (Ps 104:24) -- *or* (as here, IMO, and 1:22) "to fill", which takes an accusative as in English, "acc. of container", usually "place": earth, house, etc. You may be right about "replenish", not sure.

Comment: "to be fill with accusative material" is a rather confusing way to say it. Makes it sound like you can only use the verb with accusatory things!

Answer (score 0):

You must look at this in the spiritual realm, Jesus said the words that I speak unto you they are spirit and they are life! 1 corth 15:46 natural first then the spiritual, it takes the power of the Holy Spirit to give unto us the indepth of the scripture.

Answer (score 0):

One must question if there is any factual basis for stating: “There was no lifeform before creation of Adam , Eve and other lifeforms.” ?  The word “before” renders this belief, assumption, supposition, or speculation. A more supportable statement would be: “At the time being discussed in Genesis 1:2 and on through Chapter chapter 2, God is roughly symmarizing creating what we know of the current Earth and its inhabitants.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/48074)

Comment: As much as I agree with your point, I also have to agree that this is not an answer and belongs as a comment on the question. Please stick with us, earn a few points, and then make your comment where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Replinish.  Who were Adam and Eve replenishing? evidently the earth had been plenished with someone or something.  So, Adam and Eve were to replenish this earth again, maybe this time with humans.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on a misunderstanding of the English word 'replenish'. Even though, its usage must have been clearer to the KJV translators, some modern Bible versions such as [Modern English Version 2014](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis%201:28) also use it. One should not be distracted to semantic nuances, especially when there are various other Bible translations to compare with, and dictionaries to consult from. The Geneva Bible used "fill". The definition of replenish from [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/search/advanced/HistoricalThesaurus?q=replenish&sortOption=Frequency) includes "to fill". The re- in replenish just denotes iteration, the procreation to be repeated and continuous. It doesn't necessarily mean that the earth was full once, and you are to fill it back.

> replenish ?a1425–1833
> transitive. To occupy the whole of (a place, space, or object); to fill to capacity. Obsolete. rare after 17th cent.

Also see [etymology dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=replenish):

> replenish (v.) mid-14c., replenishen, "provide" with food or drink, also riches, beauty, etc., from Old French repleniss-, extended present-participle stem of replenir **"to fill up," from re-, here perhaps an intensive prefix based on the notion of "fill repeatedly," thus "fill completely"**

> **[re-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/re-)**:
> word-forming element meaning "back, back from, back to the original place;" also "again, anew, once more,"
> The many meanings in the notion of "back" give re- its broad sense-range: "a turning back; opposition; restoration to a former state; "transition to an opposite state." **From the extended senses in "again," re- becomes "repetition of an action,"** and in this sense it is extremely common as a formative element in English, applicable to any verb. OED writes that it is "impossible to attempt a complete record of all the forms resulting from its use," and adds that "The number of these is practically infinite ...."
>
> Often merely intensive, and in many of the older borrowings from French and Latin the precise sense of re- is forgotten, lost in secondary senses, or weakened beyond recognition, so that it has no apparent semantic content ... Recover in Middle English also could mean "obtain, win" (happiness, a kingdom, etc.) with no notion of getting something back, also "gain the upper hand, overcome; arrive at;" also consider the legal sense of recovery as "obtain (property) by judgment or legal proceedings."
>
> It was used from Middle English in forming words from Germanic as well as Latin elements (rebuild, refill, reset, rewrite), and was used so even in Old French (regret, regard, reward, etc.).
>
> > Prefixed to a word beginning with e, re- is separated by a hyphen, as re-establish, re-estate, re-edify, etc. ; or else the second e has a dieresis over it: as, reëstablish, reëmbark, etc. The hyphen is also sometimes used to bring out emphatically the sense of repetition or iteration : as, sung and re-sung. The dieresis is not used over other vowels than e when re is prefixed : thus, reinforce, reunite, reabolish. [Century Dictionary, 1895]

Answer (score -1):

The exact word וּמִלְא֤וּ is used 4 times. The first 2 occur in the creation account:

> *And God blessed them, saying, “Be fruitful and multiply, and fill (וּמִלְא֤וּ) the waters in the seas, and let birds multiply (יִ֥רֶב) on the earth.” (Genesis 1:22 NKJV)*
>
> *Then God blessed them, and God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply; fill (וּמִלְא֥וּ) the earth and subdue it; have dominion over the fish of the sea, over the birds of the air, and over every living thing that moves on the earth.” (Genesis 1:26 NKJV)*

All the life in the water is to be fruitful and multiply and to “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the waters in the seas; humans also are to be fruitful and multiply and to “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the earth. Not every type of life receives the command. On the fifth day God also makes a distinction: birds are only to multiply on the earth. On the sixth day God again makes a distinction: the other animals living on the land do not receive any command.

For humans the command to “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the earth comes with additional responsibilities:

> *Then God blessed them, and God said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply; fill (וּמִלְא֤וּ) the earth and subdue it; have dominion over the fish of the sea, over the birds of the air, and over every living thing that moves on the earth.”
> And God said, “See, I have given you every herb that yields seed which is on the face of all the earth, and every tree whose fruit yields seed; to you it shall be for food. Also, to every beast of the earth, to every bird of the air, and to everything that creeps on the earth, in which there is life, I have given every green herb for food”; and it was so. Then God saw everything that He had made, and indeed it was very good. So the evening and the morning were the sixth day. (Genesis 1:28-31 NKJV)*

Any attempt to fulfill the command will require time and impact the earth. It has been said that the command to multiply is the only one man has obeyed as  humans now occupy much of the earth.

After the first six days God finished creation by resting:

> *Thus the heavens and the earth, and all the host of them, were finished. And on the seventh day God ended His work which He had done, and He rested on the seventh day from all His work which He had done. Then God blessed the seventh day and sanctified it, because in it He rested from all His work which God had created and made. (Genesis 2:1-3 NKJV)*

Later God makes it clear the events of the seventh day were part of creation:

> *For in six days the LORD made the heavens and the earth, the sea, and all that is in them, and rested the seventh day. Therefore the LORD blessed the Sabbath day and hallowed it. (Exodus 20:11 NKJV)*

God had finished on the sixth day and it was very good. Then God’s final act of creation was to bless the seventh day.

Later God would look upon the earth and what had been very good had become corrupt:

> *The earth also was corrupt before God, and the earth was filled with violence. So God looked upon the earth, and indeed it was corrupt; for all flesh had corrupted their way on the earth. (Genesis 6:11-12 NKJV)*

As a result God decided to take action:

> *And God said to Noah, “The end of all flesh has come before Me, for the earth is filled with violence through them; and behold, I will destroy them with the earth. (Genesis 6:13 NKJV)*

God destroyed the all life with the earth. After the flood, God repeats the command:

> *So God blessed Noah and his sons, and said to them: “Be fruitful and multiply, and fill (וּמִלְא֤וּ) the earth. (Genesis 9:1 NKJV)*

Even though over 1,600 years had gone by since the first command, God’s plan for humans and the earth did not change. Just as the first 2 were to “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the earth the first 8 were to “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the earth. This is the third time the word is used.

When God explained His role in creation, He gave a command:

> *Remember the Sabbath day, to keep it holy. Six days you shall labor and do all your work, but the seventh day is the Sabbath of the LORD your God. In it you shall do no work: you, nor your son, nor your daughter, nor your male servant, nor your female servant, nor your cattle, nor your stranger who is within your gates. (Exodus 20:8-10 NKJV)*

The command(s) from Genesis remains in effect. God explains that His people are not to work continuously. They must rest each seventh day just as He rested on the first seventh day.

Man and woman were made in the image of God:

> *So God created man in Hisown image; in the image of God He created him; male and female He created them. (Genesis 1:27 NKJV)*

Being made in the image God comes with a responsibility to be imitators of God:

> *Therefore be imitators of God as dear children. (Ephesians 5:1 NKJV)*

The only way humans may correctly “וּמִלְא֤וּ” the earth is by following a repeating 7-day schedule made up of six days of work and the seventh of rest. The rest of the seventh day is not to be individual; it is to be corporate and to include animals.

The seventh day was a period of 24-hours of rest. The next day man assumed the responsibility given in the command. Today the entire earth is filled with people. As a consequence of the rotating motion which the earth was created, if everyone on the earth was to observe the seventh day of the week as a 24-hour period of rest from sunset-to-sunset, then the “evening and the morning was the Sabbath Day” would end 48-hours after it begin.

The fourth way the word “וּמִלְא֤וּ” is used is found in Ezekiel:

> *Seven days they shall make atonement for the altar and purify it, and so consecrate (וּמִלְא֤וּ)  it. (Ezekiel 43:26 NKJV)*
>
> *Do this each day for seven days to cleanse and make atonement for the altar, thus setting it apart for holy use (וּמִלְא֤וּ). (Ezekiel 43:26 NLT)*

The command given to the first man and woman, when followed for seven consecutive days would consecrate the earth setting it apart for holy use.

Comment: There's no hint of a sabbath *command* in Genesis 1, and the idea that the reason God wanted the earth to be filled with humans was so that the whole earth experienced the sabbath has no connection to the text IMO.

Comment: No, I think Genesis 1 explains itself perfectly in this case: "be fruitful, multiply, and fill the earth". It's a straightforward instruction to have lots of kids.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, it means to procreate and "fill" (replenish) the earth with human beings like them.

I think this passage is clear. Am I missing something?